# Not able to request more than 150 sites simultaneously in my node js app using npm-request library asynchronously

Tags: node.js, express

My node js app uses request npm package. It's function is to ping multiple sites ,say 200, with proper post requests and initiate respective tasks on those sites asynchronously.

i have set the timeout as 30 secs for each call.
But the timeout is being reached and the process is exiting when only 150 sites are pinged.

Is there a limitation in concurrent pinging? how do i increase that?

I think the request library is somehow limiting the concurrency level per sec to ~26, even though i initiated the pinging of 200

```
function testLoad(req, res, next) {
    let startTime = timeUtils.getCurrentTime();

    for(var i=0; i<=200; i++) {
        networkUtils.getSitePingStatus('http://somesite?id='+i, i).then((inside_i) => {
            let usedTime = (timeUtils.getCurrentTime() - startTime);
            console.log('i', inside_i, ' -- ', usedTime);
        }); //aync call using npm-request lib
    }

    return next();
}

static getSitePingStatus(url, i) {
    options.timeout= 30000;
    options.url = url;
    options.method = 'GET';
    delete options.body;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                let statusCode = 500;
                if (err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT' || err.code === 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT') {
                    statusCode = 7;
                }

                console.log('Ping error', statusCode);

                return reject(statusCode);
            }

            let statusCode = responseUtils.parseStatusCode(response);

            return resolve({sdas: statusCode, sda: i});
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and also post your code for the `networkUtils.getSitePingStatus(...)` function?

Comment: Edited and posted the code